# Question 4, chapter III, section 7 in Vinberg "Linear representations of groups. "

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, physics, topological-groups

The question and its answer is given below:

[image]

[image]

Where **T** is the unit circle, and $\Phi_{n}$ is described below:

[image] 
[image]

But I do not understand the solution,could anyone explain it for me please? or give me understandable solution as I am stucked in this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A basis of $\Phi_n$ is given by the monomials $f_m=u_1^mu_2^{n-m}$, and for $A(z)=\mathrm{diag}(z,z^{-1})$, we have $ \Phi_n(A(z))(f_m)=z^m(z^{-1})^{n-m}f_m$. Therefore $$\mathrm{tr}\,\Phi_n(A(z))=\chi_n(A(z))=z^n+z^{n-1}z^{-1}+\cdots zz^{-n+1}+z^{-n},$$
which is equal to $(z^{n+1}-z^{-n-1})/(z-z^{-1})$.

Comment: Could you please look at this question when you have time? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3168577/prove-that-the-linear-span-of-some-functions-coincide-with-the-space-of-the-foll

Comment: how is the trace of $\phi _{n}$ leads to this expression on the right?

Comment: The matrix $\Phi_n(A(z))$ is diagonalisable with eigenbasis given by the monomials $f_m$. The trace of a matrix is the sum of its eigenvalues.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3178900/a-discrepancy-in-understanding-a-solution-given-to-me-here-for-a-problem-of-vinb