# Use the theory of characters to derive the following relation for the representations of $SU_{2}.$

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, physics, topological-groups

The question is given below:

[image]

And the hint at the back of the book says:

**Establish the corresponding equality for characters.**

And this was a question I was helped on it, which establish the relation between characters and $\Phi_{n}$:  [Question 4, chapter III, section 7 in Vinberg "Linear representations of groups. "](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3166964/question-4-chapter-iii-section-7-in-vinberg-linear-representations-of-groups)

So, I end up with having $$ tr {\Phi_{m}} tr{\Phi_{n}} = \frac{z^{m+1} - z^{-m-1}}{z-z^{-1}} .\frac{z^{n+1} - z^{-n-1}}{z-z^{-1}}$$ but then what, could anyone help me in establishing the above relation mentioned in the question?

Comment: $\Phi_n$ is the representation on homogeneous polynomials of degree $n$, sending $f(x,y)$ to $f(ax+by,cx+dy)$. The LHS is tensor product of representations, the RHS is direct sum. $\sum_{j=0}^n tr \Phi_{m-n+2j} = ?$

Comment: Could you provide more details please?@reuns why you added $2j$?

Comment: How $\phi_{n}$ sends $f(x,y)$ to $f(ax + by + dy)$?@reuns

Comment: Do I have to use orthogonality relations for characters?@reuns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expand out one of the terms your expression:

$$\frac{z^{m+1} - z^{-m-1}}{z-z^{-1}} .\frac{z^{n+1} - z^{-n-1}}{z-z^{-1}} = \frac{z^{m+1} - z^{-m-1}}{z-z^{-1}} (z^n+z^{n-2}+\dots +z^{-n})$$

Do the multiplication:

$$= \frac{z^{m+n+1}+z^{m+n-1}+\dots+z^{m-n+1} - z^{-m+n-1} - z^{-m+n-3} \dots - z^{-m-n-1}}{z-z^{-1}}$$

Rearrange and collect pairs of terms from outside to inside:

$$= \frac{(z^{m+n+1}- z^{-m-n-1}) + (z^{m+n-1} - z^{-m-n+1})+\dots+(z^{m-n+1} - z^{-m+n-1})}{z-z^{-1}}$$

Comment: Since we have unitary representations of compact group it should be possible in a few lines to explain why equality of character guarantees isomorphism of representation

Comment: what about the isomorphism?

Comment: Since $SU(2)$ is a compact Lie group, the theory of characters tells us that equality of characters implies the existence of an isomorphism of representations. This is really the point of looking at characters, it let's us reduce problems about isomorphisms of spaces with compatible group actions to algebraic computations with Laurent polynomials.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3177056/show-that-the-characters-of-the-representations-phi-n-of-su2-constitute  @Nate  could you please look at this question (if you do not mind), when you have time?

Comment: and also this question (if you do not mind), when you have time please? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3178900/a-discrepancy-in-understanding-a-solution-given-to-me-here-for-a-problem-of-vinb